# Is it possible to boot Ubuntu on a TrueCrypt root partition?

Tags: encryption, truecrypt

I'm currently using LUKS device encryption to secure several machines running Ubuntu. The security and integration is nice, but the performance is considerably less impressive than TrueCrypt, and I'd like to test drive it in real life. The only problem is: I've only seen TrueCrypt used for storage in an already-running OS, I haven't seen it configured for / partition.

Has anyone done this or seen a tutorial I could check out on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible, [only Windows is supported](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=hidden-operating-system) by Truecrypts system encryption.